# how to redirect user to last visited pages by clicking back button in PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I trace user visited pages in PHP & JavaScript. I am using **`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`** function, which give me only last visited url.

For example -

I have three page **A, B & C**.

If I go from **A** to **B** and **B** to **C** page. From **C** page if I click my **Back Button** it goes back to **B**, which is correct. But from **B** page if I click **Back Button** it again goes to **C**, but I want go back to page **A**.

How can I trace my page visited history ?

Comment: Given your description, clicking back on the B page would take you to A, not to C again. If that's happening then you need to check the reason. Are you messing with the history?

Comment: have you try using `window.history.back();`

Comment: You must be changing history somewhere in the code explicitly. This is not how browsers behave. Can you also try this once using a different browser?

Comment: "Back Button" means not browser back button. Its a hyperlink in web page. where I am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in link.

Comment: Please make the hyperlink with javascript history back like `<a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1)">Back</a>`

Comment: `window.history.go(-1)` works for three pages. if use four pages. then its not working for coming back from fourth page to first page.